# Logged in on both a website and a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension

We have a file sharing service, http://ge.tt, and a few extensions for Chrome. One of them which adds extra capabilities to Gmail.

In this extension we ask users to login to Ge.tt before they are able to use the extension. Since they are already logged in on Ge.tt it would be great that they didn't have to log in again, and it causes some users to misunderstand how it works.

What would be a good way to go around and tackle this problem? Does others have the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply make an HTTP request from the extension to the user-only page to see if they are logged in. Something like `ge.tt/my-profile-ping` which returns `1` if user is logged in, `0` otherwise.

Extensions share the same cookies the browser does, so you just need to test if they are logged in and continue displaying logged-in-only data in your extension.

Also, don't forget to enable requests in your extension manifest for domain ge.tt, and www.ge.tt, and probably the https version also (if you haven't already)

Something like this in your `manifest.json`:

```
...
"permissions": [ "http://ge.tt/*", "https://ge.tt/*", "http://www.ge.tt/*", "https://www.ge.tt/*" ]
...
```

Comment: Thanks. We ended up using something similar to this :) And just a note - I dislike how Chrome acts when you change a permission in an extension. Chrome gives a message to the user which looks like a BIG error, and then is most likely to result in the user disabling the extension. Or simply just doesn't understand what it is. Would like it to act like a manual update on an Android phone where the user is simply asked to update the app manually (i.e. "click here to update manually").

Comment: bad thing is that Chrome now even disabled installing from external resources, it makes me scary what will happen tomorrow

Comment: do you know how this can be done with a google OAuthentication system? @AlexK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213239/how-to-check-in-if-user-is-logged-in-from-google-oauth2-web-server-not-client

Answer (score 6):

For example Grammarly extension can detect if you are logged in to the grammarly site

They are using this permission (and actually it is enabled on ALL sites, they can read even httpOnly cookies on any site)

[image]

[image]

N.B. don't know why they are listening for cookies, they could (as pointed by @alex-k ) just make a request to `api.grammarly.com/is-authenticated`

because I see they don't use same-site=strict or lax

this is a screenshot after I logged out and extension made request to log some action on their site, server set `anonymous` cookie to my browser

[image]

Comment: Does cookies get sent when you make API requests inside the chrome extension to the site you're already logged in to?