# google OAuth 2.0 <SecureCookieSession {}> despite being logged in

Tags: python, security, flask, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

This [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262198/logged-in-on-both-a-website-and-a-chrome-extension) mentioned that the best way to secure a website from API calls is to check whether the user is logged in/authenticated before accepting any API Calls. In my case, I am using google OAuth 2.0 to login and access user's calendar.

After countless hours on checking how to log out a user with google OAuth 2.0 , I realized that if I were to logout user from my app, the user would be logged out of google too (really bad UX) hence not so common.

Therefore, how can I still apply the website advice w/o having a log out system? As every other security protocol I tired wasn't either possible or secure enough.

How can I check if the user is authenticated from a [google OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_2), if so, accept POST requests?

As:

```
if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
```

resulted in:

```
<SecureCookieSession {}>
```

despite the user being logged in

despite the session cookies being passed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do.

1. Authenticate on UI using google oauth2 flow. Get `code` from google.
2. Send `code` to backend. Backend makes a separate api call to google using the above code to get access_token. (also means the user is legit) [more on this here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)

Basically, the above flow executed correctly means the user is who they say they are. i.e. the user has been authenticated.

3. Since user is authenticated, create a `cookie` on your own. Send the cookie to the UI as well as store it in the backend database.
4. This is the `cookie` that UI should look for while trying to authenticate an user. If cookie is present, user is authenticated, else user is unauthenticated -> redirect the user to login page.
5. Every api call should check for this `cookie` and validate by checking whether the `cookie` is present in the database.
6. When user wants to logout, delete this `cookie` on the UI and delete from backend database too. User remains logged in to his google service, but logged out of your service.

n.b. other things to keep in mind are

- session cookies should expire after a short while, 15mins / 1 hour / 24 hours depending on business needs.
- cookies should be `http only`, `secure`
- the above flow should take place strictly through HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for your response & sorry for my late reply. Wouldn't this require the user to then login every 24 hours max? which would hurt the UX. I was thinking to do what do what you said but store the cookie for server to authenticate upon matching as chrome extension have access to cookies.

Comment: Thanks for your response & sorry for my late reply. Wouldn't this require the user to then login every 24 hours max? which would hurt the UX. I was thinking to do what do what you said but store the cookie for extension to then send the cookie to server for authentication as extensions have access to cookies.

Comment: You can keep a refresh time of 6hrs. If a user makes a request to the backend 6 hrs after the cookie was issued, you renew the cookie (new hash) and reset the time to 24hrs. Delete the previous cookie. Time could be anything depending on your business requirements, might as well be 1hr / 1 week / 1 year, infinite (sometime ridiculous like 10 years).